Limit of $y_n=\frac{2n+\frac{1}{n}+3}{(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{3})^2}$ as it approaches infinity
$$y_n=\frac{2n+\frac{1}{n}+3}{(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{3})^2}$$
I saw the solution and it was $2$. But when I went to solve it using L'Hopitals rule; something else came.
When I did $y_n''$ (applying L'Hopitals rule $2$ times) the new expression is:
$$y_n''=\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}n^\frac{3}{2}}$$
which converges to $0$. So how does this make sense?

For reference ; this question is Q.7a from Calculus by Tarasov.

If I'm not wrong, after one application of L'Hospital's rule, you do not anymore have an indeterminate form (at that point, "substituting" $n=\infty$ results in the answer $2$). The next application of the rule is not valid. (Also note : L'Hospital's rule is used on functions, not sequences, but if you do get an interpolating function to have  a limit, the sequence will also have the same limit)

Probably merits being a comment more than an answer, but it's too long for that.

Minor note: $y_n''$ is not the expression you have, since L'Hopital's rule is about taking the derivative of the numerator and denominator individually.

Anyhow, a first application of L'Hopital's gives
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2 - \frac{1}{n^2}}{2 (\sqrt n + \sqrt 3) \frac{1}{2 \sqrt n}}
=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2 \sqrt n - \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}}{ \sqrt n + \sqrt 3}
$$
A second application yields
$$ 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2\frac{1}{2\sqrt n} + \frac 3 2 \frac{1}{n^{5/2}}}{ \frac{1}{2 \sqrt n}}
=
2  \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac 3 2 \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} \right)
$$
which yields $2$.

So ultimately I have no real recourse for you, since you didn't show your work in detail, other than "double check your derivatives & your algebra".

From Wikipedia:

L'Hôpital's rule states that for functions $f$ and $g$ which are defined on an open interval $I$ and are differentiable on $I\backslash\{c\}$ for a (possibly) infinite accumulation point $c$ of $I$, if $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=0\ \text{or}\ \infty$ and $g'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in I\backslash \{c\}$ and $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists, then $$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$$

Thus, you can not apply this rule for sequences. Indeed, you should convert them to functions first, i.e., define $f(x)=2x+\frac{1}{x}+3$ and $g(x)=(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{3})^2$, then since $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)=\infty$, we have $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2-\frac{1}{x^2}}{1+\sqrt{3/x}}=2\color{red}{\neq \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f''(x)}{g''(x)}}$$
since $f'(x), g'(x)$ do not satisfy the condition of L'Hôpital's rule.

However,
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2-\frac{1}{x^2}}{1+\sqrt{3/x}}
= \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2-\frac{1}{x^2}}{1+\sqrt{3/x}} \frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt x}
$$
and that manipulation produces a form which is conducive to a second application of the rule. (though if one sees the simplification you made, a second use of the rule will feel pointless - I guess it depends on how one writes down the derivative of $\sqrt x$ really)

Let us substitute $x=\sqrt{n}.$ The expression becomes
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{2x^2+{1\over x^2}+3\over (x+\sqrt{3})^2}$$ The double application of l'Hospital rule (with no simplifications on the way)  gives $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{4+{6\over x^4}\over 2}=2$$
